# Which number appeared once?

Tags: algorithm

> Given a list of 2n-1 numbers: all between 1 to n, all but one occur twice. Determine the number that occurs only once. Multiple ways preferred.

I think the problem is at fault, how can you determine which number without knowing the list of numbers?

Comment: You could iterate once over the list of numbers, adding each one to a hashmap, and then check which number only appeared once.  You could also sort the list and then walk down, noting when you don't see a number repeated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on [math.se] or some interview question site.

Comment: `I think the problem is at fault` - the whole world is, with the possible exception of me. `how can you determine which number without knowing the list of numbers?` - the "multiset" of numbers has been specified exactly, the list is thus fixed but for order.

Comment: `1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2` so if all the numbers occur twice, then the total would be `n(n+1)`. So add up the numbers in the array, and subtract from `n(n+1)` and there's your number.

Answer (score 1):

- **[O(1) space, O(n) time]**: Just take the XOR of all the numbers. Since all the numbers occur two times except one, XOR of those numbers will be zero and the single occurring number will be the result.
- **[O(1) space, O(n) time]**: As said by [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109)  in comments, we can sum all the given numbers and compare that to the sum of numbers in the range `[1, n]` which will be `n*(n+1)` (since all numbers are supposed to occur twice). The difference of the two numbers is the answer.
- **[O(n) space, O(n) time]**: Create an array of size `n` and keep the count of all the elements in the array at their corresponding positions. At the end, traverse the array, and find the number whose count is only `1`.